# Passing clojure vec to POSTGRES IN statement (?)

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, clojure, interop

I'm trying to pass an array of strings to a select statement and I keep getting the error:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of clojure.lang.PersistentVector. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

I know that the column type is correct, it looks as if passing a vector is the culprit. What is the correct way to do this?

The sql statement is formatted like so:

"SELECT * FROM said_table WHERE item_id IN (?)"

Comment: perhaps show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you are using jdbc and not korma or something like it and need to generate the sql directly instead of going through some tool:

the `in` directive requires you to crate one `?` for each item in the list. I end up using this pattern when something else requires me to build the SQL manually:

```
(let [placeholders (s/join ", " (repeat (count things-go-here) "?"))
      query "SELECT * FROM said_table WHERE item_id IN (%s)"]
    (exec-raw [(format query placeholders) things-go-here] :results)
    ....)
```